# Manage transitive dependencies separately

Tags: gradle

My company has given me an interesting problem to solve.  We have an internal Artifactory server.  For reasons, that server isn't on the internet at all, but, when everything is configured, it will provide all dependency management for every product in the company.  If a library isn't in OUR artifactory server, blow up the build and maven central and all mirrors are blocked in our firewall for typical users.  ok?  ok.

So the issue becomes getting the approved libraries and their transients from maven central to our artifactory server.  Since our server is not and never will be on the internet, it has to be done by a managers workstation.

For reasons, i have to segregate between the primary library and their dependencies.  so within artifactory, we have two repositories, it looks like this:

```
third-party <- approved libraries
transients <- transient dependencies of approved libraries
```

So, rather than trying to do this from scratch with python, i hope to be able to pull this off in Gradle.  Here's what I want it to do.

Task 1.  when libraries are approved, the manager goes to a specialized gradle build file.  they enter the typical info for the library as a dependency, no different than any other java app (they can enter multiple, but i'm going to go on like they just entered one).  They run the task.  The task will create 2 folders under build.  `Build/thirdparty`, `build/transient`.  It brings down the file they entered directly into the thirdparty folder.  This would be a complete download, lib, source, jar, pom everything.  Basically a clone of the maven repo.  Then, for any of the transient dependencies, do the same thing within the transient folder.

Task 2:  Once the user gets back into the private network (which most likely will involve walking across the street) they issue a second task.  That task will take everything in the build/thirdparty and install them into the artifactory.com/thridparty repository.  Then take everything from the transient folder and install them into the artifactory.com/transient repository.

the key is downloading the files.  is there a way in gradle that i can say put the direct dependents in this folder and the transients in that folder?

--edit

Im reading the gradle 3.0 source and I think im out of luck, unless I hack the reporting plugin and convert that into what im looking for, I get a sinking feeling here.

How about a simple one.  Getting gradle to put the libs in a folder is a piece of cake.  What about getting gradle to put the maven central pom file in the folder?  If i could create a task that allows me to do `gradle prime-cache` and have it pull down the dependency jar, pom, src, and javadocs and plop them into a folder of my choosing, I can do the rest with python.

Comment: Presumably you mean *transitive* dependencies?

Comment: yea, long day.  It looks like the DependencyResolutionListener doesn't differentiate between direct and transitive dependencies.  I'm beginning to think that the only way to make this work is to write a python script that gens a build.gradle with the transitive=false set, put that in my third party folder, then gen another one with transitive = true, then copy that to my transitive and delete the direct dependencies from it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not elegant, but might help. Assume we have a simple class that uses Spring Core, Spring Context, and Spring JDBC:

```
package net.codetojoy.service;

import org.springframework.context.*;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class UserService implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    }
}
```

Then if we track the "direct dependency" jars, we can use the `configurations.compile` to iterate over all of the jars and sort it out. See the `myTask` below:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

def buildMap(g, n, v) {
    return [group: g, name: n, version: v]
}

def SPRING_CORE = buildMap 'org.springframework','spring-core','4.3.2.RELEASE'
def SPRING_CONTEXT = buildMap 'org.springframework','spring-context','4.3.2.RELE
ASE' 
def SPRING_JDBC = buildMap 'org.springframework','spring-jdbc','4.3.2.RELEASE' 

def directDependencies = []
directDependencies << SPRING_CORE
directDependencies << SPRING_CONTEXT
directDependencies << SPRING_JDBC

dependencies {
    compile SPRING_CORE
    compile SPRING_CONTEXT
    compile SPRING_JDBC

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

def isInDirectDependencies = { jar ->
    def result = false

    directDependencies.each { d ->
        def regex = ".*${d.group}.*${d.name}.*${d.version}.*"
        if (jar.absolutePath ==~ regex) {
            result = true
        }
    }

    return result
}

task myTask << {
    configurations.compile.each { jar ->
        def isTransitive = ! isInDirectDependencies(jar)
        println "${jar.name} , isTransitive: ${isTransitive}"
    }
}
```

An alternative is to parse the output of `gradle dependences`, but the advantage of the approach given above is that one has access to the full path of the jar.

Comment: i tried to do something similar, the problem was i couldn't find the api or technique that allowed me to read what was typed into the dependencies block. I kept getting weird stuff instead of any kind of map or other object i recognized.  i tried searching the source to see how that was put together but, i couldn't find it.